Irreducible modules and composition series of an algebra.
Let $A = \left\{ \left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in M_2(\mathbb{C}) \;\middle|\; c \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$.

Consider $A$ as an $A$-module. Show that
$I = \left\{ \left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in A \right\}$ and $J = \left\{ \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in A \right\}$ are irreducible $A$-submodules of $A$, and determine if they are isomorphic.

Determine a composition series for $A$ as an $A$-module.

Determine, up to isomorphism, all irreducible $A$-modules.


This is my try:

Since $I$ and $J$ are left ideals of $A$, they are also submodules. Furthermore, they are irreducible as they have dimension $1$. As $A$-modules, they are isomorphic since an explicit morphism between $A$-modules, for example, is given by $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \mapsto 
\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

A composition series of $A$ could be, for example,
$$ 
\{0\} \subset \left\{ \left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in A \right\} 
\subset \left\{ \left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in A, 
\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in A \right\} 
\subset A.
$$

Since we are looking for the irreducible modules of $A$ as an $A$-module, we know that every irreducible module is isomorphic to a factor of any composition series of $A$, and in particular to one of those in the previous point. Therefore, up to isomorphism, the irreducible modules are



$\left\{ \left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in A \right\}$,
$\left\{ \left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in A, \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in A \right\} \mathbin{/} \left\{ \left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in A \right\}$,
$A \mathbin{/} \left\{ \left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in A, \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in A \right\}$

Now, I'm not quite sure what these two quotients are isomorphic to more explicitly. If you can provide insight, thank you.

I am considering left modules. Why is not a $A$-module morphism? i mean $\forall a \in A$ we have that $\varphi(av)=a \varphi(v)$

(2) one of those things is not even a subspace, let alone a submodule

with $\left{ \left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & 0 \ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in A, \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & b \ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in A \right} $ i mean $span \left{ \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right),\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \right}$
